# Check the stdout of a command, if is equal to value, stop for loop

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, if-statement, break

I'm trying to brute-force this pin in a challenge, The output of the nc localhost 30002 is: "Wrong! Please try Again" if its wrong. I wanted to put an IF condition to check if the output is different from "Wrong!" and stop the FOR loop

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=1000;i<10000;i++));
do
    echo "$i" | nc localhost 30002 >> /tmp/script_dir/output &
sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the test you want within the `for` loop. If the desired condition is met, [break](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html)

> break [n]
>
> Exit from a for, while, until, or select loop. If n is supplied, the nth enclosing loop is exited. n must be greater than or equal to 1. The return status is zero unless n is not greater than or equal to 1.